# Homework Question About Semidihedral Groups of Order 16.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am taking a **very** basic group theory course, and my teacher assigned us a homework assignment on semidihedral groups. There were four questions, and the fourth one is really stumping me.

The questions goes a follows:

> Consider the Following Groups: $G$ =$\langle a, x|a^8 = x^2 = e, xax = a^3\rangle$
>
> $H$ = $\mathbb Z_2 × \mathbb Z_8$
>
> A homomorphism is a map, f, from a group to a group for which $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$. Consider the map, $M$, that sends $x^b*a^c$ to the element $(b, c)$ in $H$. Is M a homomorphism? Why or why not? Write a definition of $\mathbb Z_2 × \mathbb Z_8$ in terms of generators $a$ and $b$. How do $a$ and $b$ interact in mathematical terms? i.e. what is the extra condition?

I was able to work out the first part of the question; the part about whether the map was a homomorphism or not, but the last two parts I could no figure out.

First Question: How does one use generators to define something?

Second Question: If I am able to define $\mathbb Z_2 × \mathbb Z_8$ with generators, will the answer to the second part become much clearer?

Please try to keep your answer as simple as possible so that I can actually understand what you're saying.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is actually misleading. There's no presentation for $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_8$ that just adds an extra condition to the presentation above.

Comment: I don't believe that's what the question asks for - I don't want to spoil it for OP but it seems to be asking for an extra condition on the new generators $a$ and $b$ to ensure they do in fact generate $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_8$, and not some larger group.

Answer (score 1):

First question: The generators generate the group, in the sense that any element of the group is a product of the generators. So, if you have defined $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$, then since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, there is only one choice for, say, $\phi(a^2 b^{-1} a b^2)$, since it must be $\phi(a^2 b^{-1} a b^2) = \phi(a)^2\phi(b)^{-1} \phi(a) \phi(b)^2$. As every element of the group can be written as something like this, specifying $\phi$ on the generators defines the homomorphism.

Second question: Yes.

Comment: please tell me what ϕ means

Comment: I was using $\phi$ to refer to some group homomorphism that we are trying to define.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer

Comment: Would this work:

Comment: $H=<(a,b)|a∈ \mathbb Z_2, b∈ \mathbb Z_8, (a^2,b^8)=(e,e)>$